# Virtual functions and detouring

Tags: c++, gcc, virtual-functions, detours

I've been programming with detours lately and all that comes with it. I have detoured a lot of different functions; thiscall, stdcall, cdecl, virtual functions etc. But there is one thing I haven't managed (which might not even be possible), and that is to hook a base class virtual function. For example; there is a Car class which declares a virtual function (empty) `Drive`. Then there are 3 other car classes which inherits car and implements `Drive`.

If I hook the Car's (base class) `Drive` function (using a simple 'jmp' hook) would it be triggered by the descendants of `Car`, when they trigger `Drive`, if they do *not* call the base function?

To explain even more thoroughly:

```
class Car
{
   virtual void Drive(void) { } // Empty virtual function
}

class Lamborghini : public Car
{
   void Drive(void) { // does lots of stuff, but does NOT call base function }
}
```

So I'm wondering whether the base method get's called or if it can be hooked somehow? Does the function exectution jump *directly* to `Lamborghini::Drive` or does it somehow pass through the `Car` class so it's detectable whenever a descendant calls `Drive`?

EDIT: And if the base class function is empty, is it even possible to hook it, since it requires 5 bytes of space?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table and also this might help since it does what you're describing: http://code.google.com/p/gmodmodules/source/browse/trunk/gm_slog/gm_slog/vfnhook.h?spec=svn74&r=74

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the base method does not get *automagically* called. The dynamic dispatch mechanism will detect which *override* it needs to call and that will be the function that gets called. This is usually implemented by means of a virtual table (vtable) that stores the pointers to the *final overriders* for each virtual function in a class. When dynamic dispatch is used, the compiler injects an indirect call through that table and jumps to the proper function.

Note that the vtable actually holds pointers to *thunks* or *trampolines* that can potentially modify `this` (implicit first argument) before forwarding the call. The advantage of using this approach is that if `this` does not need to be updated, the compiler can jump directly into the final overrider. At any rate, you can take advantage of this feature and modify the vtables to point to your own code (i.e. you can update the pointer in each vtable --one per type-- to refer to your own *thunk* or *function*)

Comment: Just to avoid any misunderstandings; it is possible, and all I need to do is to modify the virtual table? And if that is the case, I also want to ask (because of lack of knowledge), does the vtable only consist of 4-byte pointers? Or is there anything else I should now (i.e is it only to find the vtable and the offset, then replace that pointer to point at my 'hook')?

Comment: @ElliottDarfink yep, you only need to find the vtable and replace the pointer. Also it might be 4 bytes, but might not depending on your computer's architecture.

Comment: @ElliottDarfink also make sure you realise that you should replace it with a _member function_ so the function doesn't think it can use the ecx register and lose the `this` pointer.

Comment: The virtual table is compiler-defined. Modifying it is a really bad idea: code bloat, and not portable even accross different versions of the same compiler...

Comment: @Synxis Lucky for me I only care about GCC and Linux 32bit :)

Comment: One other thing.  Detours rewrites the beginning of the target function address (saving the original instructions that it replaces in a location called the trampoline) which jumps to your detoured code.  When you call that function from within the detoured code, it will execute the saved instructions and then jumps back to the original code.  This is why it doesn't matter how big the size of the `jmp` call is.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, method Drive in your Lamborghini class will be called based on table of virtual functions. If you want to call a Drive method of a base class, you must write something like `Car::Drive;`. And base class needs some space because of the VTBL. Hope I've unanswered on your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, you want `Car::Drive` to be called each time `Lamborghini::Drive` is called, even if `Lamborghini:Drive` does not call directly the base function ?

For that, the simplest method is to use an 'inner' function, which will be virtual (and protected), whereas the initial method will be non-virtual and will route the call.
Here's an example:

```
class Car
{
    void Drive(void)
    {
        // ...
        Car::innerDrive(); // Base function call
        // ...
        this->innerDrive(); // 'Derived' function call
        // ...
    }
protected:
    virtual void innerDrive(void) { } // Empty virtual function
}

class Lamborghini : public Car
{
protected:
    void innerDrive(void) { // does lots of stuff, but does NOT call base function }
}
```

Comment: The problem is, I'm working with pre-compiled code, that's why I'm using detours :)